# Is it possible to undervolt modern intel chips in Ubuntu?

Tags: intel, cpu

I've tried to patch kernel with PHC, installed the cpufreq PHC thing, but these don't work on modern pstates intel chips.

Repasting my cpu and undervolting with ease in XTU on windows, and would love to reduce power/heat/noise on ubuntu also.

Comment: That's normally something you do in your BIOS.

Comment: Are you having a specific problem that you'd like help with? What is "repasting my cpu"? What is "PHC"? Is your computer overheating? Etc...

Comment: I'm trying to undervolt in Ubuntu on modern pstate intel chips. To my knowledge, after trying these avenues, it can't be done. Hence the question, "is it possible to undervolt on 17.04? I know what PHC is. I repasted my CPU. My computer isn't overheating.

Comment: On modern laptops, undervolting is not normally done in BIOS. It can be done easily in Windows with Intel XTU. And it could be done on ancient Intel chips in Ubuntu with PHC.

Comment: Would love to have this answered definitively too.  I dual-boot with winidows where I have it nicely undervolted via XTU,  but doesn't seem to persist when I reboot into Ubuntu.

Comment: @MikeLawrence I honestly can't tell whether or not it's persisting in Ubuntu, because I can only run Ubuntu on integrated intel graphics, or Nvidia graphics, 100% either way. Battery difference between the two is huge, and dwarfs the finer difference between CPU normal volted and CPU undervolted.

Comment: @MikeLawrence Finally. Check out my answer below. We've waited years for this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IT'S FINALLY POSSIBLE!

https://github.com/georgewhewell/undervolt

```
tom@159560:~$  sudo undervolt --re
temperature target: -3 (97C)
core: -110.35 mV
gpu: -65.43 mV
cache: -110.35 mV
uncore: -110.35 mV
analogio: -110.35 mV
```

There is also another way that I've seen some other people having success with, but it seems the other way is more Archy, and this way is more Ubuntuey.